# Batch->Queueable->Callout+DML ::: Uncommited work pending issue

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, queueable-interface, queueable-apex

I am having following structure, where I am getting issue- CalloutException: Uncommited work pending.

Ideally, with Queueable it should not throw the same error(since DML is happening at last in queueable). Not sure why, somewhere my assumptions are getting wrong.

The execution sequence is ideally as follows:

**Batch Execution**

FOR LOOP

1. Callout-Only first time --> Getting token
2. Callout -- Output A
3. Queueable -- Passing output A

**Queueable**

1. Callout -- Getting token
2. Callout -- Getting earlier output A and pass as input--Output B
3. DML -- Storing the output B

BatchClass

```
global with sharing class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts
{
    global String token = NULL;

    global Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        List<DummyObject> dummies  = [ SELECT *** FROM DummyObject WHERE ***];
        return (Iterable<SObject>) dummies;     
    }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<SObject> scope){
        if(token == NULL){
            token = Util.getToken();//just a plain callout(not fancy here)
        }

        List<DummyObject> dummies = (List<DummyObject>)scope;

        for(DummyObject dummy : dummies){
            if(token != NULL ){         
                try{
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                    //prepare a request
                    Http http = new Http();
                    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);//failing here in second iteration
                    if( res.getStatusCode() == 200)
                    {
                        String firstOutput = res.getBody();                        
                        System.enqueueJob(  new QueueableClass(dummy.Id , firstOutput)  );
                    }
                    else{
                        //callout-to-send-issue-to-Admin-SYNC
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    //callout-to-send-issue-to-Admin-SYNC
                }
            }
            else{
                //callout-to-send-issue-to-Admin-SYNC
            }
        }
    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Queueable:

```
public with sharing class QueueableClass implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    public String dummyId = NULL;
    public String firstOuput = NULL;


    public QueueableClass(String dummyId, String firstOuput){
        this.dummyId = dummyId;
        this.firstOuput = firstOuput;
    }


    public void execute(QueueableContext qc){
        String token = Util.getToken();//just a plain callout(not fancy here)

        try{
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            //prepare a callout
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            if( res.getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                DummyObject dummy = new DummyObject(Id = this.dummyId);
                dummy.storeMe = res.getBody();
                update dummy;
            }
            else{
                DummyObject dummy = new DummyObject(Id = this.dummyId);
                dummy.storeMeWithError = res.getBody();
                update dummy;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            DummyObject dummy = new DummyObject(Id = this.dummyId);
            dummy.storeMeWithError = 'Exception :' + e;
            update dummy;
        }

    }
}
```

Ideally it should separate out transactions. However it's not doing the same. Any solution/work-around would be helpful.

Comment: you can try chaining them in separate queuable for each

Comment: yes, I can do that. However, if I do blindly without knowing the reason, it can be dangerous with Production. Hence waiting for proper explanation of this behavior.

Comment: Where does it fail? Can you show us the code for just the failing transaction? And this is in real use, right, not in a unit test?

Comment: I think that seeing the code is going to be important here. The execution sequence you outlined looks like it should work, so there's gotta be some detail in the implementation that's causing things to deviate from it. About the only thing I can think of is that you could see that behavior if you're just calling the `execute()` method for your queueable directly instead of going through `System.enqueueJob()`

Comment: @DavidReed - its actual transaction not part of test class. It work for first part(not the second iteration of batch). Due to IP issue, I can't share code here.

Comment: @DerekF yes, I am calling EnqueueJob(not the direct method call). It's passing the result of 2nd callouts to queueable.

Comment: There's a few things that are DML-equivalent that can cause this to happen (like setting a Savepoint). I agree with Derek that it will be very difficult to solve without seeing the code or a representation of the code. Can you anonymize it?

Comment: @DavidReed - I updated flow. Let me see how I can have a psuedo code.

Comment: Savepoint - is not there(not any Database class methods).

Comment: @DavidReed I added code blocks.It's almost similar to existing flow(just names changed).

Comment: @DerekF I added code blocks.It's almost similar to existing flow(just names changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `System.enqueueJob()` is causing the database state to be changed.

That method causes a record to be inserted into the `AsyncApexJob` object (that's what the jobId you get back from `System.enqueueJob()` points to), and thus you find yourself in the "pending work, commit or roll back" situation.

Fixing this will require you to remove the `System.enqueueJob()` call(s) from your for loop in the batch class.

If this external system can only generate a single valid token at a time (i.e. token1 expires once token2 is issued), then you'd probably need to go off-platform (or Heroku) to act as an intermediary.

Comment: I will try the same, however a doubt - what if I collect a map of 2 values and iterate in for loop after the existing for loop(with less than 50 jobs). Is it a recommended way?

Comment: @YsrShk not entirely sure what you're suggesting here, but I think you're describing storing the (objectId, token) pair in a map so you can iterate over it and call `enqueueJob()` outside of your existing loop. That's probably the approach I would take myself. I don't really think there's a "best practice" here other than keeping with the Salesforce theme of "work on collections, not individual records"

Comment: yeah kind of bulkified enqueueJobs. I will try the same. Thanks for the answer though, it was a good learning!